# How to upload dmp files to server using breakpad on Android?

Tags: android, google-breakpad

I want to collect the C++ side crash information of my Android app using breakpad.

I have build the breakpad toolchain successfully, and I can symbolicate stack traces correctly.

#### My question is :

How to upload the minidump files to my server on Android? Is there a solution in breakpad source code?

Or I should implement this all by myself?

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a pity that nobody answer this question...
So I just implement this upload operation all by myself.

Comment: This was the right answer, there's no code included in Breakpad to upload minidumps on Android. The Android SDK provides HTTP libraries, so it's not that hard to implement. You can find the code that Firefox uses on Android here: http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/2949e808ed33/mobile/android/base/CrashReporter.java#l243

Comment: I'd like to ask same question for Windows, but I'm pretty my question would be close as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this example code to upload breakpad crashes to hockey:
https://github.com/ashtom/breakapp

I've done the same for my project and works fine. Hockey has an api that you can access all the data. Or you use their backend.